# How to use Spring REST Projections with custom controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-rest

I have the following Projection which return a name of a tag:

```
@Projection(types = NewsTag.class, name = "newsTag")
public interface NewsTagProjection {

    @Value("#{target.tag.name}")
    String getName();
}
```

I'm using it in the following repository which is responsible of newsTag model:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = NewsTagProjection.class)
public interface NewsTagRepository extends JpaRepository<NewsTag, Integer> {
}
```

so when i call the news repository which have a list of NewsTag:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Integer> {
}
```

everything works fine, and it return a list of tags with the nae only.
but if i want to use a custom controller with the same endpoint (lets say i'm doing that for the error handling), it return me only the news without the list of tags, like the projection doesn't exist.

and here's the controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("news")
public class NewsController {

    private NewsService newsService;
    private PagedResourcesAssembler<News> pagedAssembler;
    private NewsResourceAssembler newsResourceAssembler;

    @Autowired
    public void setNewsService(NewsService newsService) {
        this.newsService = newsService;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    public void setPagedAssembler(PagedResourcesAssembler<News> pagedAssembler) {
        this.pagedAssembler = pagedAssembler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setNewsResourceAssembler(NewsResourceAssembler newsResourceAssembler) {
        this.newsResourceAssembler = newsResourceAssembler;
    }

    // Return all news with pagination
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllNews(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<News> newsPage = this.newsService.getAllNews(pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.pagedAssembler.toResource(newsPage, this.newsResourceAssembler));
    }
}
```

**Edit**
NewsResourceAssembler:

```
@Service
public class NewsResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<News, Resource<News>> {

    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Autowired
    public void setEntityLinks(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<News> toResource(News news) {
        Link self = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).withSelfRel();
        Link newsTags = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).slash("newsTags").withRel("newsTags");
        Link newsComments = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).slash("newsComments").withRel("newsComments");
        return new Resource<>(news, self, newsTags, newsComments);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide `NewsResourceAssembler.class` code?

Comment: @drowny see my edit, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wants to add all fields of News, you can manipulate returned object of **ResponseEntity**. So i changed with this code , can you apply to your code ?

`NewsResourceAssembler.class` should be like ;

```
@Service
public class NewsResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<News, Resource<NewsResource>> {

    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Autowired
    public void setEntityLinks(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<NewsResource> toResource(News news) {

        Link self = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).withSelfRel();
        Link newsTags = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).slash("newsTags").withRel("newsTags");
        Link newsComments = entityLinks.linkFor(News.class).slash(news.getId()).slash("newsComments").withRel("newsComments");

        final NewsResource newsResource = new NewsResource();
        //set any fields to which do you wants to send client
        //newsResource.setExampleFields();
        //newsResource.setNewsTagList(news.getNewsTag()); //example code. Change according to your models

        return new Resource(newsResource, self, newsTags, newsComments);
    }
}
```

Now you need to `NewsResource.class`, so this should be like this ;

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class NewsResource extends ResourceSupport {

    //private fields of which do you wants
    //dont forget list of newstag field
    //ex : private List<NewsTagFields> newsTag = new ArrayList<>();

    //Also should write getter and setter methods
}
```

PS: dont forget the commented line's rules. According to this change , your client should analyse the incoming response to the client. Because in response , some links rel should be changed on main object. But your custom params didnt change.

**EDIT :** 
If in your `NewsResource.class` -->  field of `newsTag` should be like (*Please dont forget to set all tags in your resource assembler class!*) ;

```
private List<NewsTagFields> newsTag = new ArrayList<>();
```

And now you need to NewsTagFields.class . Also you can use this class ;

```
public class NewsTagFields {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    public NewsTagFields(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And finally add this code into `ResourceAssembler` to add new NewsTagFields list ;
(*This code provide to get all **newsTag** and convert to list of **NewsTagFields** totally. And adding to **newsResource** to send to client*)

```
final List<NewsTagFields> allNewsTag =
                news.getNewsTag().stream()
                        .map(newsTag -> new NewsTagFields(newsTag.getId(), newsTag.getName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        newsResource.setNewsTagList(allNewsTag);
```

Comment: Thanks, now i get the fields that i give in NewsResourceAssembler, the only problem is that the newsTag in the the response is empty, actually should return 4 newsTag object which it does but the objects are empty, should print the id and name but i get `"newsTag": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {}]`

Comment: You should write a new model for assembler which is match with NewsTag entity. I edited the answers with EDIT:  can you check ?

Comment: but if i did that i can't do `newsResource.setNewsTagList(news.getNewsTag());` in the assembly because it's gonna be type mismatch, also i can't do `newsResource.setNewsTagList(news.NewsTagFields ());` because news class has no NewsTagFields field.

Comment: Let me to clarify wait pls

Comment: ok thanks. just for your information newsTag is a middle lodel between news and tag. It have Tag object and News Object

Comment: I know the middle model. So you can convert to middle model correctly. I updated the NewsTagFields and also new code to end of post. Can you try ?

Comment: Good luck my friend , I'm glad to help you. it workeds i think ?